# How can I stop Chrome blocking me setting a window.location after the user has changed the URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window

I open a new window to point at a page in a manual with `var manual_win = window.open("", "manual");`
I then set the location (after a bit of async code that tests the existence of the page) with `manual_win.location = url;`
This works and opens the manual page in a new named tab. I can later run the same code with a different URL and it works fine.
If the user edits the URL manually on the named tab to be some other site such as google.co.uk then the code no longer works on Chrome 76. It just brings the tab to the foreground and doesn't change the location. There is no issue with Firefox. I presume this is due to some sort of popup blocking logic in Chrome.

Is there any way to get around this?

It seems like a bug in Chrome that it blocks me from changing the location yet still brings it to the foreground. It would have made more sense for it to have cleared the name from the tab when it took control way from me so I end up opening a new tab instead.